# NetBeans, why do some projects appear as coffee-cups and others as folders?

Tags: java, netbeans, projects-and-solutions

I'm working in NetBeans 6.8 and I want to add projects that I had previously deleted from NetBeans workspace but not from my computer. Some appear as coffee-cups and can be opened fine but others appear as folders and cannot be opened. How can I open these projects (see image).[image]

Comment: Are the deleted ones the ones not recognized?

Comment: Koshinae - Correct, they just open up like another file structure instead of being open-able as a project.

Comment: That explains, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Delete` action on a project states "This will delete project Xyz so that it cannot be opened in the NetBeans IDE anymore.", which explains the situation. It removes the `build.xml` file and the `nbproject` directory from the project directory, rendering it unrecognizable.

You'll need to make a new project, and use the `Java Project with Existing Sources` as a project type in the dialog.

Specify the project name again, and set the Project Folder to the existing project folder. Then specify the src directory.

Note: All your extra libraries and JARs are lost, you'll have to re-add them to the project.

Next time just `Close` the project to hide it in the Projects tab.

Comment: You are spot on with the closing instead of deleting, Thanks for advice worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

open Netbeans
file-> new project
from categories -> java and from projects choose "java projects with existing source" -> next button

give any new name to project and choose some different location ->next
"Existing sources"  dialog box will come then press button "ADD folder"
choose java project folder